# Applying function to several matrices with similar names

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, sum, assign

I have a 1864 matrices (7 x 7 dimensions) saved in the global environment, called "probability_matrix[i]" e.g: probability_matrix1, probability_matrix2, etc...

I have generated these matrices using:

```
    for (i in 1:length(lambda.p)){
assign(
paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = ""), 
dpois(0:maxgoal, lambda.p[i]) %*% t(dpois(0:maxgoal, mu.p[i]))
    )
}
```

Now I'm attempting to sum some of the elements of the matrices and them save them as a row vector. I can write it for each individual one, but I'm trying to use a "for loop".

```
HomeWinProbability1 <- sum(probability_matrix1[lower.tri(probability_matrix1)])
HomeWinProbability2 <- sum(probability_matrix2[lower.tri(probability_matrix2)])
HomeWinProbability <- rbind(HomeWinProbability1,HomeWinProbability2)
```

I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(lambda.p)){
assign(
paste("HomeWinProbability", i, sep = ""), 
sum(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = "")[lower.tri(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = ""))])
      )
}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Error in sum(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = "")[lower.tri(paste("probability_matrix",  : 
invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

How would you go about it? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you try `sum(get(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = ""))[lower.tri(get(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = "")))])` in place of `sum(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = "")[lower.tri(paste("probability_matrix", i, sep = ""))])`?

Comment: the `get()` seemed like the missing link here

Comment: Yes! It worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!